# How can I hide or show a div based on if there is content in two textboxes using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 textboxes on a page and they both have the class "OrderEntry".

I want it so if there is any text in either of of these textboxes, it will show the div with ID "OrderPanel".  If the textboxes are cleared, backspaced or empty, it will hide the div "OrderPanel".

So, the page loads, "OrderPanel" is hidden and both "OrderEntry" textboxes are empty.  A user types a single character into either one of the textboxes and the "OrderPanel" is shown.  If BOTH of the "OrderEntry" textboxes are empty, then the div is hidden.

I tried subscribing to the $(".OrderEntry").keydown() event but it seemed to apply both independently.  Which means it would still show hide if one was empty and not based on both?

Any clues on how to do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use keypress I think, but that's just my preference.

In the keywhatever function, check both textboxes.

```
$( '.OrderEntry' ).keydown(function(){
    var content = false;
    $( 'OrderEntry' ).each(function(){
        if( $( this ).val() != '' )
            content = true;
    });
    if( content )
        $( 'orderPanel' ).show();
    else
        $( 'orderPanel' ).hide();
});
```

Or something similar

Comment: I might also make all that stuff a function, and call it on keypress or blur, in case they use their mouse to do stuff.

Comment: I was halfway typing that when you posted :-)

Comment: Good answer. Similar to mine, but with actual code (I'm lazy..) +1

Comment: @KP sometimes I like to give a fish, sometimes I like to teach to fish. Today was a give a fish sorta day.

Comment: lol good perspective. BTW I've updated my answer - I think the OP wanted to base the show/hide on all entries (not any). Reversed the bool so that it would take that into account.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. Basically on the key event of choice (keydown, keypress, etc.) rather than showing `.OrderPanel` immediately, do a check on the contents of the `.OrderEntry` entities. If they both have values, show the panel, if not, don't.

**EDIT:**

To add to `hookedonwinter's` thought - I think the OP wants the panel to only show if all entry fields are completed, so I'd invert the boolean flag in your example to:

```
$( '.OrderEntry' ).keydown(function(){
    var content = true;
    $( 'OrderEntry' ).each(function(){
        if( $( this ).val() == '' )
            content = false;
    });
    if( content )
        $( 'orderPanel' ).show();
    else
        $( 'orderPanel' ).hide();
});
```

That way, if *any* of the `.OrderEntry` fields is empty, `.OrderPanel` isn't shown.`

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
$('.OrderEntry').change(function() {
  var bothEmpty = true;
  $('.OrderEntry').each(function() {
    if($(this).text().length > 0) {
      bothEmpty = false;
    }
  });
  if(bothEmpty) {
    $('#OrderPanel').show('slow');
  } else {
    $('#OrderPanel').hide('slow');
  }
});
```